# 50% width on masonry elements

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

Currently i'm trying to apply a masonry layout to my site using [Masonry.desanto](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

The problem if i need the first two block to size 50% of the total parent width, but i can't manage to do that using this library. The seconds element ALWAYS goes below the first one. no matter if i use some css like width: calc(50% - 100px).
See an example here: https://codepen.io/josebelisario/pen/JjXvPKL

```js
// external js: masonry.pkgd.js

$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
  percentPosition: true,
  horizontalOrder: true,
  gutter: 15
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px);
}

.grid-item {
  color: white;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  background: #D26;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }
.grid-item--height3 { height: 260px; }
.grid-item--height4 { height: 360px; }

.item-40 { width: calc(40% - 30px); }
.item-50 { width: calc(50% - 30px); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<h1>Masonry - fluid columnWidth</h1>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item-50">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-50">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-40">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">9</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-40 grid-item--height3">10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">11</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">12</div>
  <div class="grid-item">13</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-50 grid-item--height2">14</div>
  <div class="grid-item item-40">15</div>
  <div class="grid-item">16</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">17</div>
  <div class="grid-item">18</div>
  <div class="grid-item">19</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height3">20</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">21</div>
  <div class="grid-item">22</div>
  <div class="grid-item">23</div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-item--height2">24</div>
  <div class="grid-item">25</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific example, you need to think of the lowest common denominator (think fractions) for your `.grid-sizer` class. (In this case, your grid looks like it is supposed to be 6 columns, of which the 50% boxes take up 3/6 and the regular `.grit-item` boxes take up 2/6. To be safe with width calculations in masonry grids, I never round up the % either, so your `.grid-sizer` width should probably read `width:calc(16.66% - 15px)`

One other thing to note as well... if you want the vertical and horizontal gutter space to be even, subtract the same value in pixels from your equation (instead of `33.33% - 30px` try `33.33% - 15px`. That will give it that true masonry grid look.

I've provided updated CSS for your example below. Copy and paste that into your CodePen and you should see a big improvement.

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #EEE;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer{
  width: calc(16.66% - 15px);
}
.grid-item {
  width: calc(33.33% - 15px);
}

.grid-item {
  color: white;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  background: #D26;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.grid-item--height2 { height: 200px; }
.grid-item--height3 { height: 260px; }
.grid-item--height4 { height: 360px; }

.item-40 { width: calc(40% - 15px); }
.item-50 { width: calc(50% - 15px); }
```

Let me know if this answer worked for you! :)

Comment: Marked it as accepted because it solves what i was asking about, but for my case i ended up rewriting a simpler masonry script that behaves exactly as i want. Thank you

Comment: Glad you got it working to where you need it to be! :)